# concatenate list by user input (string) and displaying the List

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

1) hi i want to create a program where the User can input strings and it add on as list.

```
eg cmd : "hello "
   cmd : "every "
   cmd : "one "
'hello' 'every ' 'one'

a = 0
while a < 3:
    b = str(raw_input("cmd : "))
    list1 = [b]
    a += 1

print list1
```

issue i am having is adding up string to list on every loop ! i am missing some logic argument for this to happen.
these string i would like to assign later on to some function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List1 = []
for a in range(2):
    b = raw_input("cmd :")
    List1.append(b)
    a += 1
print List1
```

After going through the forum answer and by "korylprince" this is the code i come-up with which do exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You need an append `list1 += [b]` instead of assignment `list1 = [b]`

And in Python in this case its better to use `for in`. Also raw_input would return a string, you do not need to convert it

```
for a in range(3):
    b = raw_input("cmd : ")
    list1 += [b]
```

Or even better to use list comprehension as there is an overhead for appending a list.

```
list1 = [raw_input("cmd : ") for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: I think it would be more pythonic to use list1.append(b) (should be more efficient also since the [b] object doesn't have to be created.)

Comment: `List1 = []
for a in range(2):
    b = raw_input("cmd :")
    List1.append(b)
    a += 1
print List1`